# Convex Hull Mess Axis Label

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry, labeling

```
 P0={0,0};
    P1={1,0}; 
    P2={-1,0}; 
    R[1]=ConvexHullMesh[{P0,P1,P3},Axes->True ]
```

I use this code to draw the convex hull but I want to also label the axes and give colors to the region. I used Axes-> True but the plot does not show all the 4 axes but only 2. I want all 4 of them. Is it also possible to add text to the diagram as well and resize the diagram?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "4 axes"? Perhaps you wanted the `Frame` option?

Comment: I mean I want the x-axis from negative to positive values and the same for the y-axis. But the plot with Axes-> True only shows the positive values of x and y. How can I set the axis range?

Comment: *How can I set the axis range?* You're probably looking for the `PlotRange` option.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks. You are right. I'm now able to set the range. But when I also want to label some discrete points.
I use the following command:
Show[Region[R[1],PlotRange->{{-1.5,1.5},{-1.5,1.5}}, Axes->True],Graphics[Point[{{0,0},{0,1},{1,0}}]]]
This only shows a black spot at the point. But how do I add text at those points to label them? like (0,0), (1,0) and (0,1).

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments, especially not ones which would benefit from formatting, they're just too difficult to read.  Either edit your original question, or ask a new one.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yeah. I'm sorry. I got it.
Show[Region[R[1],PlotRange->{{-1.2,1.2},{-1.2,1.2}},Axes->True,ImageSize->Medium],Graphics[Text["(0,0)",{0,0}]],Graphics[Text["(0,1)",{0,1}]],Graphics[Text["(1,0)",{1,0}]],Graphics[Text["Choice [1,2] and [6,2]",{0.7,1}]]]
I used the Text[] option to label the points.